# Running Graph library with nodebox on windows + None Type Error

Tags: python, nodebox

I have installed **nodebox 2** for windows on my machine and have verified that all the examples are running as it is.

Now i want to use graph library [Graph](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph) for the same.

I went and copied it as it is in my site-packages folder and then ran the examples it had given along it in IDLE.

I recieved an error of *ximport* . So then i added in the code as `from nodebox.graphics import *`

Now i get the following error

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\graph\graph_example2.py", line 39, in <module>
    g.draw(highlight=path, weighted=True, directed=True)`

`File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\graph\__init__.py", line 453, in draw
    self.update()`

`File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\graph\__init__.py", line 416, in update
    self.x = _ctx.WIDTH - max.x*self.d - min_.x*self.d`

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WIDTH'`

Is there any way I can run this library from outside of nodebox in windows ?

thanks...

I am pasting the code for which i get the error below...

```
from nodebox.graphics import *
try:
    graph = ximport("graph")
except ImportError:
    graph = ximport("__init__")
    reload(graph)

size(600, 600)

# A graph object.
g = graph.create(iterations=500, distance=1.0)

# Add nodes with a random id,
# connected to other random nodes.
for i in range(50):
    node1 = g.add_node(random(500))
    if random() > 0.5:
        for i in range(choice((2, 3))):
             node2 = choice(g.nodes)
             g.add_edge(node1.id, node2.id, weight=random())

# We leave out any orphaned nodes.
g.prune()

# Colorize nodes.
# Nodes with higher importance are blue.
g.styles.apply()

# Update the graph layout until it's done.
g.solve()

# Show the shortest path between two random nodes.
path = []
id1 = choice(g.keys())
id2 = choice(g.keys())
path = g.shortest_path(id1, id2)

# Draw the graph and display the shortest path.
g.draw(highlight=path, weighted=True, directed=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Nodebox Graph docs mention](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph) that it supports Nodebox 1.9.5.6, which is a Nodebox 1 (Mac only) version number. To my knowledge the Graph library has not yet been ported to Nodebox 2, so can only currently run on the Mac.

---

One option is a project called Nodebox OpenGL which implements the Nodebox API and includes its own graph library, with an example of using it under `examples\08-physics\07-graph`. The Nodebox 1 Graph library is not yet compatible, but it includes its own graph class [`nodebox.graphics.physics.Graph`](http://www.cityinabottle.org/nodebox/physics/#graph).

To use it, you'll need to download:

- [Nodebox for OpenGL](http://www.cityinabottle.org/nodebox/)
- [pyglet cross platform multimedia library](http://www.pyglet.org/)

Extract these and install, or just place the `nodebox` and `pyglet` packages somewhere on your Python path (`site-packages`). When you run `07-graph.py` you should see this:

[image]

Comment: There's a slight problem with this answer, it gives directions for Mac OS X users while the questionnaire is specifying his OS as Windows.

Comment: Yep, the mention of the `Graph` library is what threw me off -- it only runs on the Mac. Updated the answer with that info and a workaround.